# How do I work with a list returned from the result in AppleScript?

Tags: applescript

AppleScript newbie here. I have a rather simple question that I can't seem to find an answer online. I promise I've spent several hours to find the answer on my own but either I'm not searching the right keywords or I'm not reading the right resources. So here it is:

I have successfully scripted a code to tell an application to return user information as the result. However, the result is returned as a list and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to manipulate it or use it. Here's an example of what my result looks like:

```
{{"FIRST_NAME", "LAST_NAME", "PHONE_NUM", "USER_EMAIL", "USER_ID", "USER_TITLE"}}
```

If I want to get just the USER_ID, how would I achieve this? It cannot be that hard I'm sure, please don't skewer me for not figuring it out on my own. I've read through the entire "Manipulating Lists of Items" section in [Apple's Scripting Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/ManipulateListsofItems.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH48-SW1) but like other resources I've read, they are all working with a list that is user defined, not what's returned from the result.

Here's what I've tried:

```
Return item n of result
```

or

```
Return item n of result as string
```

I get the "Can’t get item n of" error, so I tried assigning the result to a variable as list like

```
set theList to result as list
Return item n of theList
```

Still doesn't work. Then I tried to make the result to a string but then it gives me EVERYthing as one long string which it's hard to manipulate.

```
FIRST_NAMELAST_NAMEPHONE_NUMUSER_EMAILUSER_IDUSER_TITLE
```

I've even tried a handler from the Apple Scripting Guide and was able to get the result in a string with space in between. Again, I can't manipulate it.

Is it possible to pick one item from the list of the result? I feel like I'm approaching this completely wrong. Thank you SOOOO VERY much for your input and education.

Also thank you for tolerating my very novice inquiry.

Comment: Now that I think about it, I remembered I actually tried to get item 2-5 of result... had I freaking tried item 1 I would have noticed that it returned the entire list as result and hopefully figured out the nested list situation.... but again maybe I’m giving myself too much credit lol. Thank you all for the wonderful help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your *list* is nested, please note the number of braces `{{ ... }}`

The outer list contains **one** item which is the inner list.

This code displays each field in a dialog

```
set theList to {{"FIRST_NAME", "LAST_NAME", "PHONE_NUM", "USER_EMAIL", "USER_ID", "USER_TITLE"}}
set fields to item 1 of theList -- gets the inner list
repeat with aField in fields
   display dialog aField buttons {"OK"} default button 1
end repeat
```

or to get an item at specific index

```
set userID to item 5 of fields
```

Don't coerce a string to a string and a list to a list, both coercions are redundant.

Comment: Ahhhhh I KNEW IT!!! I actually took notice that the result has two brackets but as a self-taught newbie I had no idea what to do to get it out of the double bracket. Then eventually just thought I may be over thinking. BUT I WAS RIGHT! UGHHH Thank you x1000!!! P.S. I don’t even know the proper name of “{{ }}” I saw “double curved bracket” elsewhere but that’s different.

Answer (score 1):

What you have there is a list of lists, so (assuming the inner list always has the same structure):

```
set aList to {{"FIRST_NAME", "LAST_NAME", "PHONE_NUM", "USER_EMAIL", "USER_ID", "USER_TITLE"}}

item 5 of item 1 of aList

--> "USER_ID"
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! Gosh I actually noticed it but just didn’t know what to do with it or think of it as the issue lol I loved the simple approach of getting a list of a list and I’ll keep that I’m mind moving forward. Sorry I can only pick one answer but yours helped just as much!! Much thanks!!